# Is this complex integral well solved?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have this exercise:

> $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\cos z}{z^3}dz$$

The way I tried to solve it was:

> Since we have a singularity in $0$, and it is *inside* of the curve, lets consider the new curve: $|z|=1/2$, then by the deformation theorem and Cauchy's integral formulas, we get that: 
>   $$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\cos z}{z^3}dz=\int_{|z|=\frac 12}\frac{\cos z}{z^3}dz=2\pi i(-\cos (0))=-2\pi i$$

Is this correct? I think I followed all the hypothesis correctly, but this puzzles me, since $0$ is still *inside* the circle.

Comment: It's not correct (the integral isn't $0$). What was the idea behind using the smaller circle?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh yes you are right, $\cos (0)=1$ oops. I got the idea of the smaller circle from another two examples, but my confusion took over. We have that $\frac{\cos z}{z^3}$ is analytic in $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$, the unity circle is in there but in the example that I saw they changed to a smaller circle, however in this case I don't see if this matters, since Cauchy's formulas works as long as the curve is closed.

Comment: Right, it does not matter at all. The integral over all circles with centre $0$ is the same, independent of the radius. But, your result is still not correct. I suppose you have $-\cos 0$ from taking the second derivative of $\cos$ since the denominator is $z^3$? You forgot to divide by $n!$ (where in this case $n = 2$).

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm such a dummy... you are right I forgot part of the formula. But apart from that, in the essential part of solving the problem, the deformation theorem is not needed?

Comment: Right, we don't need the deformation theorem, all that matters is which singularities of the integrand are wound around how often.

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem.**$^1$ If $f$ is analytic inside and on the simple closed positively oriented contour $\Gamma$ and if $z$ is any point inside $\Gamma$, then
>   $$
> f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta\quad(n=1,2,3,\dots).
> $$

By the theorem stated above, we get
$$
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\cos z}{z^3}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{2!}(-\cos 0)=-\pi i.
$$
Also, the deformation theorem is not needed as Daniel Fischer commented.

---

$^1$ [Fundamentals of Complex Analysis: with Applications to Engineering and Science](https://books.google.co.kr/books/about/Fundamentals_of_Complex_Analysis.html?id=4R90DAAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y), page 211